# I Have No .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, compression, server

I am simply trying to enable gzip compression, but i have no .htaccess file on my server (apache). I can see all hidden files in my FTP (including .htpasswd), but no .htaccess. Can I just create a new .htaccess file if I do not have an existing one?

Comment: You can also add compression to your conf/httpd.conf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default empty `.htaccess`. You can add `.htaccess` file in any site directory, depending on your needs. It's just a simple text file, that must be saved using the name `.htaccess`.
As the name starts with a dot the file is not visble from outside (online).
If it concerns the whole site, you must place it in the root of the site in the same directory as the index / home page of the site.
You will find many examples on this site with tag [.htaccess](/questions/tagged/.htaccess).